JavaScript heap out of memory in Github runner
I have a pretty large react frontend that keeps running out of memory whenever I tried building it in github action.
However, if I build the app on my local machine it always builds fine.
I've tried all options to increase the running memory of the runner which all proved abortive:
Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:20 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./

RUN npm install -g node-gyp

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build # This is running out of memory all the time within the runner

FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build-stage /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx/client_temp

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Here is the script section of my package.json file where the build script is called:
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/craco start --verbose",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/craco build --verbose",
 }

And finally here is the ci.yaml worfklow file:
name: Build Docker Image and Push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
       NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=4096" //This doesn't even work as I expected

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "20"

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}" | docker login -u "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}" --password-stdin

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          file: Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: "*redacted*"


I will really appreciate any ideas on how to resolve the JavaScript heap out of memory.

Add space after colon i.e. NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=4096". Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to lint your workflows.

@Azeem thanks for your response. The space is there in my workflow file. I've also corrected it in the question. Still no luck

So probably use large runner or https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/using-larger-runners/running-jobs-on-larger-runners?platform=linux or self-hosted runner. env:        NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=4096" don't you want to add this to dockerfile? You are building a docker, why set shell variable? Is setup-node relevant, there is no node call.

@KamilCuk I've already tried setting the NODE_OPTIONS in the Dockerfile before now and the issue is still there. I eventually had to remove it

Can you try to add  argument : --optimize-for-size before  craco start/build command? For example:     "build": "NODE_ENV=production node --max-old-space-size=4096  --optimize-for-size  ./node_modules/.bin/craco build --verbose",
